# Is it possible to automate customization of the "Developer Portal" in Azure API Management?

Tags: rest, azure, deployment, azure-api-management, azureportal

The dilemma we face with API Management is being able to deploy the custom Developer Portal (customized through the APIM publisher portal UI) changes to each different environment (QA and PROD) without requiring manual configuration for each of those environments.  Is this possible?  The only way I can think of making this possible is through a REST API in the Publisher Portal for managing developer portal configurations.  Is there a REST API for this?  And if not, are there near term plans for this?

In the screenshot below, it would be ideal if the bottom UI configuration processes could be automated somehow:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no API present at the moment to control these options. You best bet is git integration, but that might not be quite convenient.

Comment: Content didn't include in the source control method. [for more include please visit](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/42c7f901-212c-420f-956a-fe584e871ccc/automation-of-portal-styles-using-api-or-equivalent-approach?forum=azureapimgmt) [Please vote this wish in APIM](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/34378729-ability-to-import-and-export-cms-content-mangament)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can show the Iframe on the developer portal and that Iframe can be deployed on the azure and that page you can write your logic.

I did it one of the portals but there is only one problem the design problem and also the authentication problem you have to authenticate service every time you open the IFrame.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Git configuration is the only option [but it doesn’t cover artifacts which created via CMS UI](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/42c7f901-212c-420f-956a-fe584e871ccc/automation-of-portal-styles-using-api-or-equivalent-approach?forum=azureapimgmt), the static content like such as welcome page, etc.

FYI, And the [Git base solution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-configuration-repository-git) requires that the instance becomes read-only (or locked to a single-user) during operation.

[Please vote this wish in APIM](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/34378729-ability-to-import-and-export-cms-content-mangament)