# CI/CD / Rebuild a Azure APIM developer portal content

Tags: azure, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, azure-api-management

In the Azure APIM, is it possible to manage the content in a programmatic way -let's say the REST API or SDK- when I have some changes in Developer Portal content?

I saw there are some [articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109232/is-it-possible-to-automate-customization-of-the-developer-portal-in-azure-api) mentioned to use the `iFrame` but it is still required to have manual change in portal. For CI/CD, the requirement is make everything as code. So when writer updated / create / rebuild content in the APIM platform, we can use the Jenkins or another tools to make it change.

Comment: You mean the developer portal UI or API definitions?

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is not possible to natively manage developer's portal content programmatically, with the exception of data generated by API Management (e.g., API descriptions or API operations are fetched live and API Management's API call response is mapped to UI).

However, there are plans to allow for more control and automation with regards to developer portal content, customizations and deployments.